# Not able to understand the /\%([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/pack('C', hex($1))/eg regular Expression

Tags: php, perl

I have given a task to Convert a Perl function to PHP 
But while doing the same ,I came across a regular expression which is Perl and not able to find its alternative in PHP

```
 Perl Function :

sub UrlDecode{
 my $android_desc = shift;
 $android_desc =~ tr/\+/ /;
 $android_desc =~ s/\%([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/pack('C', hex($1))/eg;
 return $android_desc;
}
```

I am not able to understand the functioning of this function & also I am not able to convert the same in PHP .
Can anyone please help me .

Comment: Note that `pack('C', hex($1))` is less easy to read, and rather slower than, the equivalent `chr hex $1`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to translate your Perl function line by line as PHP already brings this functionality. The Perl code is equivalent to [the PHP builtin `urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$var =~ s/PAT/EXPR/eg` is an operator that replaces all instances of strings matching regex pattern `PAT` in `$var` with the result Perl expression `EXPR` (evaluated for each match).

`\%([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})` is a regular expression that matches a percent sign (`%`) followed by two hexadecimal characters. Two the hex characters are captured.

`pack('C', hex($1))` is a Perl expression that returns the character indicated by the captured hex string.

As a whole, the `UrlDecode` function is used to decode components of URIs, as does PHP's builtin [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php). However, you should simply use `$_GET['myvar']` or `$_POST['myvar']` if you're trying to extract CGI form variables.

Comment: can you please tell me that how to implement the same thing in php

Comment: See the last paraphraph.

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression replaces the hexadecimal representation of a number as a string and replaces it with the character represented by that number.

For example, `4A` is the hexadecimal representation of `74`. So the regex would replace instances of the string `%4A` with the character represented by the number 74.

```
my $str = "%4A"; 
my $str  =~ s/\%([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/pack('C', hex($1))/eg; 
print $str;
# J
```

Note that the replacement side of the substitution is Perl code, *not* regex syntax. The `e` switch at the end of the `s///` means that Perl should evaluate the replacement section as code and use the result as the replacement.

`pack` is a useful but somewhat obscure function used to encode and decode binary data in various ways. In this case it's taking a number (`hex($1)` converts the caputred hex number to base 10) and returning a byte of data (a character) representing that number. You will have to know the encoding scheme used in the encoded url to make sure that character is being interpreted correctly in whatever application is using it.